# Iphone App Keyboard

Tags: iphone, ios5, ios6

Im looking to make an Emoji/emoticon app for the Iphone with my own custom Images, I want the option of integrating it with the keyboard, but from what I see on here its not possible? I see some apps on the App store that have different images then the Regular Emoji that can be integrated into the keyboard, so is it possible or is it better just to go the copy to clipboard route. Thanks

Comment: You can create your own keyboard and attach to a text view as `self.myTextview.inputView = customKeyboardView;` You need to have your own implementation to add the characters to textview. I am not sure you can add images to textview using this.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to do that.
There is a lot of emoji apps in the appstore and all the icons are same.
since iOS 6 released the emoji keyboard are included there.